# How to check if a word starts with a digit, in Perl

Tags: perl

Below is my code to check if the word starts with a digit:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    my $domain_name = @ARGV;

    my $first_letter = substr(($domain_name),0,1);
    print STDERR "first letter is $first_letter \n";

    if($first_letter eq  '0' || $first_letter == 1
       || $first_letter == 2 || $first_letter == 3 || $first_letter == 4
       || $first_letter == 5 || $first_letter == 6 || $first_letter == 7
       || $first_letter == 8 || $first_letter == 9) {

            print STDERR "$first_letter start with digit\n";

    } else {

            print STDERR "$domain_name does not starts with a digit\n";
    }
```

But when I am printing the `$first_letter`, it is always displaying `1`. Please help.

Comment: `\d` matches 460 characters. If you just want to match 0..9, use `[0-9]` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print "first letter is digit\n" if $ARGV[0] =~ /^\d/;
```

Answer (score 10):

**First problem:** `@ARGV` is an array. When you do `my $domain_name = @ARGV;`, you are using an "array" in the context of a "scalar" (i.e. simply put, you're trying to assign an array to a scalar).

In such cases, `perl` replaces the usage of the array, with the number of elements in the array. In this case `1` (because the `@ARGV` array appears to contain 1 element). Instead, what you really want to do is find out if the first element in `$ARGV[0]`, the first argument, is a digit.

**Second problem:** You should use regular expressions for this sort of thing. A correct implementation would be a single line:

```
print "First letter is digit\n" if $ARGV[0] =~ /^\d/;
```

`=~ /^\d/` means: 'starts with a digit'.